# How to start using javax.swing.Timer if I already have my own Timer class?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I made a class called Timer with some custom actions.

Then I found out that there is a class javax.swing.Timer that does just what I need.

So I renamed "My" Timer class to another name (using Refactor button in NetBeans), and inside of it did something like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 5000);
```

But it didn't work - it gave the error that construct Timer requires some variables that my old class needed. So it refers to old class, not javax.swing.Timer.

Can anyone please tell me what's going on?

Tried to do this:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer();
timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 5000);
```

but it didn't work too

Comment: First; is this a GUI application or not? Only use the swing Timer for a swing application. Second, what does "didn't work" mean? We're going to need the compiler error or stack trace to help you.

Comment: You may want to look at java.util.Timer instead of javax.swing.Timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the Swing Timer API before trying to code it. It has no `schedule(...)` method that I know of, and you can't just make up methods and expect them to work.

A Swing Timer has only **one** constructor one that requires you to pass in an int delay and an ActionListener, one whose actionPerformed method is called every `delay` ms:

```
int delay = 1000; // 1000 ms == 1 second
javax.swing.Timer myTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(delay, 
       new MyTimerActionListener());
myTimer.start();
```

Important Links:

- [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Swing Timer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: the error is with construct, not the method. so `Timer timer = new Tiemr()` doesnt refer to javax.swing.Timer

Comment: There is a schedule() methoed in java.util.Timer however. I believe there is some confusion here about which Timer class is being used.